# Breakpoints not getting hit in netstandard project referenced by Android project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, .net-standard

My Xamarin Android project has a reference to a .NetStandard project.
Breakpoints in the Android project work fine but they don´t in the .NetStandard code. Is there any workaround to fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the support for ppdb is not quite here for Xamarin. Thus the implied `<DebugType>portable</DebugType>` in a dotnet standard .csproj is not compatible.

You should be able to hit breakpoints in your dotnet standard library by adding the following into your dotnet standard library's .csproj:

```
<DebugType>Full</DebugType>
```

This will go back to the default debug type of "full" instead of ppdb(portable pdb)

https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/Documentation/diagnostics/portable_pdb.md#supported-scenarios

If there's a need for a conditional, you can go back to the following:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>Full</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

or

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdb-only</DebugType>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

However the release `<DebugType>` is a bit redundant.